# Easy combinatorics - how many ways to...

Tags: combinatorics

On how many ways can we set **x** signs on **y** positions?

**y >= x**

for example we can set one sign on two positions on 2 ways:

@.

.@

Comment: With at most one sign per position allowed, $y\choose x$

Comment: Are the signs different?

Comment: All sings are the same.